# (SSH 2FA) Public Key OR Password + PAM Google Authenticator

Tags: ssh

I am trying to get a conditional combination of Two-Factor Authentication for my SSH Server (*OpenSSH_6.7p1*) but after reading and reading I couldn't find how to setup what I thought. I have just found this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130016/use-public-key-or-password-and-pam-verification-code) with the same case as me (better explained too) but unsolved.

I have setup a 2FA method with Google Authenticator TOTP following the steps described [here](https://sysconfig.org.uk/two-factor-authentication-with-ssh.html).

What I want to achieve when trying to log in:

If a valid key is provided, then ask for the TOTP.
 If no key is provided, ask for the account password, and then for the TOTP.

I successfully configured other options like:

- Publickey + Password + TOTP Google Authenticator (1)
- Publickey + TOTP (2)
- Password + TOTP (3)

What it means, I changed `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` to `yes`in `sshd_config`. I have already commented the line `@include common-auth` in `pam.d/sshd` for the case 2. I also have tried different options for the `AuthenticationMethods` directive in the file `sshd_config` (case 1,2).
After reading the man of SSH, I can guess that the problem is in `pam.d/sshd`:

*UsePAM  Enables the Pluggable Authentication Module interface. If set to
             "yes" this will enable PAM authentication using
             ChallengeResponseAuthentication and PasswordAuthentication in
             addition to PAM account and session module processing for all
             authentication types.

             Because PAM challenge-response authentication usually serves an
             equivalent role to password authentication, you should disable
             either PasswordAuthentication or ChallengeResponseAuthentication.*

I would be really thankful if someone could give me some advice about how to proceed (in case it is possible to achieve). Thanks.

Comment: You can use https://cern-cert.github.io/pam_2fa/ which is trying to achieve something similar. But this exact configuration you are trying to achieve is almost impossible to set up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked what on the link says and you are right. The only thing I could achieve is to be asked two times for the TOTP, but waiting between until the next code is generated makes it not really handy.